How to make only words (not sentences) in SRT file by AssemblyAI
Okay... So Im trying to create a video making program thing and I'm basically finished but I wanted to change 1 key thing and don't know how to...
Here's the code:
import assemblyai as aai
import colorama
from colorama import *
import time
import os

aai.settings.api_key = "(cant share)"

print('')
print('')
print(Fore.GREEN + 'Process 3: Creating subtitles...')
print('')
time.sleep(1)
print(Fore.YELLOW + '>> Creating subtitles...')
transcript = aai. Transcriber().transcribe("output/output-tts.mp3")

subtitles = transcript.export_subtitles_srt()
print('>> Created subtitles!')

f = open("subtitles.srt","a")
f.write(subtitles)
print('')
print('Program >> You are going to have to manually run the last python file [addsubtitles.py] because \n this program needs to close to write down the subtitles')
print('')
time.sleep(7)
f.close()

when it exports the SRT it exports it something like this:
1
00:00:00,160 --> 00:00:04,238
Put a finger down if you have ever kissed a

2
00:00:04,286 --> 00:00:05,374
goddamn dog.



but i want it to go word by word but still synced with the time frame in the audio and then generate a srt file that has word by word and no sentences.
How could I do this? because I have no idea how to implement that into the code.
I tried watching or searching the internet for any ways on doing this because I can't figure it out but there are still no results. Would appreciate if anyone could help.

I'm not familiar with assemblyai, but a quick source check yielded this typing class with a list of options you can set. Maybe you can try to set punctuate or format_text to false.

Also not familiar with assemblyai, but looking at the source the export_subtitles_srt method has an argument to limit the number of characters in each caption which is a bit of a hack but might give you what you need. Failing that it would be fairly straightforward to take the list of words and time stamps from the transcript and generate your own SRT, which would likely give you better control on the output.
